# EF Core retrieve rows grouped by a value from a column

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, ef-core-3.0

Let's, for example, take a table like this (Data has to be in one table):

[image]

And I want to get a result JSON like this:

```
[
    {
        "manufacturer" : "VW",
        "cars" : [
            {
                "id" : 1,
                "model" : "Golf"
            },
            {
                "id" : 3,
                "model" : "Passat"
            },
            {
                "id" : 6,
                "model" : "Polo"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "manufacturer" : "Renault",
        "cars" : [
            {
                "id" : 2,
                "model" : "Laguna"
            },
            {
                "id" : 5,
                "model" : "Clio"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "manufacturer" : "Ford",
        "cars" : [
            {
                "id" : 4,
                "model" : "Fiesta"
            }
    }
]
```

The problem is that when I try to get manufacturers in a distinct list and then loop with foreach to get the data, I get an error about Data Reader already opened.

```
var manufacturers = _context.Cars.Select(s=> s.Manufacturer).Distinct();

foreach(var m in manufacturers)
{
   var sublist = _context.Cars.Where(q=> String.Equals(q.Manufacturer, m).ToList();
   // Add sublist to the specified models field (list)
}
```

And I have a model that has a field for the manufacturer and a list of cars.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, get the cars from database with:

```
               var carsList = context.Cars.ToList();
```

This way, you are executing the query against the database and you will get all the car objects list in memory, so you can perform complex query operations with this list.

In your case:

```
            var list = carsList.GroupBy(x => x.Manufacturer).Select(x => new
            {
                manufacturer = x.Key,
                cars = x.Select(y=> new 
                {
                    id = y.Id,
                    model = y.Model
                })
            }).ToList();
```

But if you try to make this query directly in database,

```
var list = context.Cars.GroupBy(x => x.Manufacturer).Select(x => new...
```

if you are using EF Core 3.0 and above, you will have a client vs server evaluation runtime exception, by default is activated in Ef Core 3.0.

More detailed info, here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/client-eval

Comment: Thank you, this is the approach I was searching for.
However, I had to add another Select after getting the initial list from the database. In my real case, I am grouping by field from another table so I am using navigation properties and then I get a null reference in a GroupBy clause. If I project fields first everything works fine. Do you know why is this happening?

As for the exception, I am not getting any, all works fine with EF Core 3.1.1

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following,

```
var result = _context.Cars.GroupBy(x => x.Manufacturer).Select(x => new { manufacturer = x.Key, cars = x.Select(y => new { id = y.Id, model = y.Model }).ToList() }).ToList();
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result);
```

PS: You can use AsNoTracking() in a read-only scenario for much much better performance like

```
_context.Cars.AsNoTracking()...
```

For more details, visit [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/tracking)

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
manufacturers.Group(m=>m.manufacturer)
```

you can get a new data structure, it contains `key(manufacturer)` and `value(List<cars>)`.